# space complexity to find a subtree

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

Can anybody tell me why the following code takes memory: O(logN) + O(logM)?
The code is to solve a problem: given big tree T1, small tree T2, check whether T2 is subtree of T1. Note size(T1)=N and size(T2)= M. In fact I did not see any additional memory was taken except for the bool results of subtree() and matchTree(). But IMO this memory should be O(1). Please correct me if I am wrong.

```
boolean containsTree(TreeNode t1, TreeNode t2) {
  if (t2 == null) return true; // The empty tree is always a subtree
  else return subTree(t1, t2);
}

boolean subTree(TreeNode r1, TreeNode r2) {
  if (r1 == null)
   return false; // big tree empty & subtree still not found.
  if (r1.data == r2.data) {
    if (matchTree(r1,r2)) return true;
  }
  return (subTree(r1.left, r2) || subTree(r1.right, r2));
}

boolean matchTree(TreeNode r1, TreeNode r2) {
 if (r2 == null && r1 == null)
     return true; // nothing left in the subtree
 if (r1 == null || r2 == null)
     return false; // big tree empty & subtree still not found
 if (r1.data != r2.data)
     return false; // data doesn’t match
 return (matchTree(r1.left, r2.left) && matchTree(r1.right, r2.right));
}
```

Comment: Does memory include stack usage?

Comment: @DKrueger. I am not sure. I am trying to understand. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function calls itself recursively, so although you are not explicitly using memory, the stack will cost O(h1) + O(h2) in the call stack. If the tree is sufficiently balanced, this is the same as O(logn) + O(logm).

Comment: is recursive qsort() still called in place sorting?

Comment: Could be - it depends. Compiler might optimize the program a lot.

Comment: Thanks. I understand why O(logN) + O(logM) now. Do you mean qsort is in place because it uses tail-recursive? If yes, isn't the above code use tail-recursive either? If no. what does your "depends" mean? sorry for different questions. all I want to know is how to calculate space complexity Thanks,

Comment: Normally recursive qsort is indeed O(logn). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#In-place_version. And if by in place you means O(1), then it is not.

Comment: Wiki said: "Quicksort operates in-place on the data to be sorted as it only ever swaps two elements. However, most implementations require O(log n) space to keep track of the recursive function calls as part of the divide and conquer strategy; so Quicksort is not an in-place algorithm."

Comment: @user389955: Quicksort is called *in-place* because it never copies the actual elements out of the input memory. It sorts them *in-place*. Some other sort algorithms (e.g. Mergesort) need to copy the elements into a new block of memory while they are being sorted. These are called *out-of-place*. Note that there are variations of most sorting algorithms that are *in-place* or *out-of-place*, so these names can only accurately be applied to an *implementation*, and not generally to an algorithm.

Comment: @yzt My thoughts exactly at first - but if you Wiki in-place algorithm is gives a definition that says only constant additional space algorithms qualify, and quicksort is used as a counter example there. This definition is a bit unexpected, IMO.

Comment: @yzt and Ziyao Wei: I understand what inplace means: constant additional space not increased with size. All I want to confirm now is: if sb. asks me what is space complexity of qsort, whether I should answer O(1) or O(logN). I used to think it as O(1) since it is in-place. But based on Ziyao Weis link from wiki, it seems O(logN) is the answer.

Comment: @user389955: I used to think that qsort's space complexity was O(logN), but I would have called it *in-place*, since it didn't copy the input. It seems that I was wrong about the definition of "in-place". But qsort is O(logN). However, in my opinion, you can only define these things for a particular implementation of an algorithm. It might be possible to write qsorts that are better or worse than this.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, since (most implementations of) qsort's worst case time complexity is O(N^2), its space complexity can also be said to be O(N) in the worst case.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion takes stack space, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: maybe. see my comment to Ziyao Wei. Thx